# Galois group of $x^4-5$

Tags: galois-theory

How do I find the Galois group of $x^4-5$ over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$?
I've managed to do so over $\mathbb{Q}$ but I don't know how to find the others.

I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: How did you do it over $\mathbb{Q}?$ What did you get?

Comment: The splitting field of $x^4-5$ over Q is $Q(^{4}\sqrt{5},i)$, [F:Q]=8 so $|G|=8$ and thus it's isomorphic to $D_4$, is that correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $\;x^4-5=(x^2-\sqrt5)(x^2+\sqrt5)\;$ , the polynomial's roots are $\;\pm\sqrt[4]5\;,\;\pm\sqrt[4]5\,i\;$ .

But $\;x^4-5\in\Bbb Q(i)[x]\;$ is irreducible, otherwise either

$$\sqrt[4]5\in \Bbb Q(i)\implies \exists\,a,b\in\Bbb Q\;\;s.t.\;\;\sqrt[4]5=a+bi$$

which we know is possible in $\;\Bbb C\;$ iff $\;a=\sqrt[4]5\;,\;\;b=0\;$ (equality in $\;\Bbb C\;$) , or else it can be factored in the product of two quadratics over $\;\Bbb Q(i)\;$ , which is now easy to see it's impossible (as the factoring above happens in $\;\Bbb C[x]\;$ , which contains the involved fields's polynomial rings)

Thus,

$$[\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]5):\Bbb Q(i)]=4\implies \text{the Galois group wanted is the cyclic}\;\;C_4\;\;or\;\;C_2\times C_2$$  Knowing what the full Galois group is shall help to find out which one it is .

Try now to do something similar for the other cases.

**Added on request:** For example, over $\;K:=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-5})=\Bbb Q(\sqrt5\,i)\;$:

The polynomial $\;x^4-5\in K[x]\;$ is irreducible, otherwise either

$$\pm\sqrt5\in K\iff \exists\,a,b\in\Bbb Q\;\;s.t.\;\;\pm\sqrt5=a+b\sqrt5i$$

or else

$$\pm\sqrt[4]5\,,\,\pm\sqrt[4]5i\in K\implies \exists\,a,b\in\Bbb Q\;\;s.t.\;\;\begin{cases}\pm\sqrt[4]5\\\pm\sqrt[4]5i\end{cases}=a+b\sqrt5i\implies$$

and both cases lead us to contradiction (check this!), thus

$$[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]5\,,\,i):\Bbb Q(\sqrt5 i]=4$$

Comment: I've tried the other cases using your explanation and I'm still struggling, is there any chance for another hint? Thanks!

Comment: As you indicate, $\sqrt{5}$ is neither in $\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i})$ nor in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$. Therefore $x^2\pm\sqrt{5}$ is neither in $\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i})[x]$ nor in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})[x]$.

Comment: Oh, rats! You're right, @ccorn. Thanks. I just messed up with my own notation. Editing on its way later.

Comment: And $[\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i},\sqrt[4]{5}):\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i})] = 4$, not $2$.

Comment: That was edited loooong ago, @ccorn..and it is $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt5i)\;$ , not $\;\Bbb Q(i)\;$

Comment: I mean the part after the first "Thus,".

Comment: The part after "thus" follows from the above , unless that's mistaken, @ccorn, and I see there no $\;2\;$ . What's your point?

Comment: I mean the part *before* the "Added on request". Paragraphs 2...4.

Comment: I wonder how in the hell did this answer got upvoted so much and accepted so much with all those inaccuracies and typos there. Thanks, @ccorn, and I shall check this more thoroughly later as I have to run now.

Comment: @DonAntonio, you're welcome.

Comment: The reason that $x^4-5$ is irreducible over Q is not sufficient in your answer. An reducible polynomial may not have any root over Q.

Comment: I know that, @WeiZhou . In what part "it is not sufficient" and for what?

Comment: First displayed equation. It suffices to show $\sqrt{5}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i})$, as this implies $\sqrt[4]{5}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i})$, and it is clear that $\mathrm{i}\in\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i})$. (The product of two roots would have to be $\mathrm{i}^k\,\sqrt{5}$, which is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i})$).

Comment: Aaaah, I now see how I did mess up so badly this thing !! When editing the question, before or after your first comment above @ccorn, I "cut" a complete line and pasted it elsewhere, and I messed up between $\;\sqrt5\;$ and $\;\sqrt5\,i\;$ ...oh, my!

Comment: I meant above: between square and fourth roots.

Comment: @DonAntonio, sorry for misunderstanding your answer.

Comment: Don't worry, @WeiZhou: that happens to us all...specially to me...:)

Answer (score 28):

You have already found that the splitting field is
$E=\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i},\sqrt[4]{5})$
and that $\operatorname{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})\cong D_8$ (I use the algebraic
convention where the index denotes the group order, not the vertex count).
Therefore the other fields you cited are intermediate fields $K$
between $E$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.
Use the [fundamental theorem of Galois theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory),
that is, find the subgroup of $\operatorname{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$
whose members fix $K$.

First, let us find a suitable presentation for
$G = \operatorname{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$.
A straightforward choice is $G = \langle\tau, \sigma\rangle$
where $\tau$ is complex conjugation, thus
fixing $\sqrt[4]{5}$ and sending $\mathrm{i}$ to $\tau(\mathrm{i})=-\mathrm{i}$,
and $\sigma$ fixes $\mathrm{i}$ while rotating $\sqrt[4]{5}$
to $\sigma(\sqrt[4]{5})=\mathrm{i}\sqrt[4]{5}$.
Therefore $\tau$ has order $2$, $\sigma$ has order $4$,
and $\sigma\tau=\tau\sigma^{-1}$.

It remains to find subgroups of $G$ that fix the various intermediate fields
$K$. The index of such a subgroup in $G$ must equal the extension degree
of its fixed field over $\mathbb{Q}$.
That is, subgroups of order $d$ dividing $8$
correspond to intermediate fields of degree $8/d$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
For example, $\sigma^2$ fixes $\mathrm{i}$ and $\sqrt{5}$, therefore
the order-$2$ subgroup $\langle\sigma^2\rangle$ fixes the degree-$4$
extension field $\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i},\sqrt{5})$.
It fixes no larger field, as that would violate the index condition.
Likewise, $\tau$ fixes $\sqrt[4]{5}$ and thus fixes $\sqrt{5}$ as well,
so the order-$4$ subgroup $\langle\tau,\sigma^2\rangle$
fixes the degree-$2$ extension field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$.

I have made a diagram that contains some more intermediate fields.
If I got it right (check it!), we have the following correspondence,
showing fields together with the subgroups of $G$ that fix them.
Arrows mean "extends" for fields and "is subgroup of" for Galois groups.
$$\begin{matrix}
 &&&& \substack{\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i},\sqrt[4]{5})\\\{1\}}
\\ &&& \swarrow & \downarrow & \searrow
\\ && \substack{\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i},\sqrt{5})
 \\\langle\sigma^2\rangle}
 && \substack{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5})
 \\\langle\tau\rangle}
 && \substack{\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i}\sqrt[4]{5})
 \\\langle\tau\sigma^2\rangle}
\\ & \swarrow & \downarrow & \searrow & \downarrow & \swarrow
\\ \substack{\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i})
 \\\langle\sigma\rangle\cong C_4}
 && \substack{\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i}\sqrt{5})
 \\\langle\tau\sigma,\sigma^2\rangle\cong V_4}
 && \substack{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})
 \\\langle\tau,\sigma^2\rangle\cong V_4}
\\ & \searrow & \downarrow & \swarrow
\\ && \substack{\mathbb{Q}
 \\\langle\tau,\sigma\rangle\cong D_8}
\end{matrix}$$
The third row contains what your question has sought.
$C_4$ means a cyclic group of order $4$, $V_4$ means Klein's Four group.
Note that the diagram is not complete: I left out e.g.
$\mathbb{Q}\left((1-\mathrm{i})\sqrt[4]{5}\right)$
which is fixed by $\tau\sigma$ and extends $\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i}\sqrt{5})$.
You may want to complete the diagram to get the full picture.

Comment: Fair is fair: up to now, this question should have been more upvoted and, eventually, perhaps even accepted (though perhaps the OP hasn't yet covered the FTG). +1

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks. Originally, I just hinted at the fundamental theorem. I rarely engage in such questions although solutions to exercises in Galois theory tend to be pleasant.